# How can i prevent duplicate insert datas from date in my attendance

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Hello everyone goodevening, i have a question.. how can i prevent duplicate insert data to my database. my logic is when he IN in morning and the date is march 7 2019
he insert and when he attempt to IN again in march 7 2019 the message box will show that ("He Already In") and when he In March 8 2019, he can In again in short if he IN now he can be In on another day again how can i fix this i have some codes here

```
 MySqlDataReader dr;
        if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from attendance1 where empID=@empID AND Name=@Name AND Date=@Date", con);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@empID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empID.ToString();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label6.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(label4.Text);

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (dr.Read())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are already In");

        }
        else
        {

            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO attendance1(empID,Name,Date,MorningIn)values(@empID,@Name,@Date,@MorningIn)", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@empID", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empID.ToString();
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label6.Text;
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@Date", MySqlDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(label4.Text);
            cmd1.Parameters.Add("@MorningIn", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = label2.Text;
            cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("OK");


        }
        if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
```

he error because the connection is open... what strategy can i do ?

Comment: Remove the second `con.Open()`, and also for best practices employ a `using ( )` around your connection. Then you should be able to execute both your commands. Is the question that you're having SQL trouble or that your queries are not working?

Comment: @NibblyPig i do that but the error is still connection is open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are opening the connection twice here,

1) Remove all `con.Open(); and con.Close()`

2) Add after MySqlDataReader dr;

```
if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   con.open();
}
```

3) In the end in the last command line write

```
 if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
   con.close();
}
```

Comment: in else of last cmd1 the con.close?

Comment: if{}else{} then if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
   con.close();
}?

Comment: you're going to use the connection in your if and else, so you should open your connection before,                                                                                                   if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
   con.open();
}                                                                                                                                IF {} ELSE{}                                                                                                              if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
{
   con.close();
}

Comment: I edit my code in the top. is that correct sir AhmadMM ?

Comment: if u opened the connection before any actions and close it after there wont be any problems in your connection

Comment: ohh ok so i open it in another action then close ? again

Comment: if it's in the same code batch, function..etc  no, if it's in a different batch,function..etc yes